# Readline does not read user config specified in INPUTRC variable

Tags: linux, bash, readline

I am trying to change the location of my inputrc. [The docs](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/readline.3.html) say that it reads the config location from the INPUTRC environment variable

> Readline is customized by putting commands in an initialization file (the inputrc file). The name of this file is taken from the value of the INPUTRC environment variable

I exported this variable in my `~/.bash_profile`

```
export INPUTRC="~/.config/readline/inputrc"
```

and added the following lines to `~/.config/readline/inputrc`

```
$include /etc/inputrc

# Case insensitive tab completion
set completion-ignore-case on

# Single tab partially completes and shows all options
set show-all-if-ambiguous on

# shift + arrows to go back and forth one word at a time
"\e[1;2D": backward-word
"\e[1;2C": forward-word

# Cycle through completions inline 
Tab: menu-complete
"\e[Z": menu-complete-backward
```

Now if i try to open a new bash session, none of these options seem to have taken effect. It works as expected if I put them in `~/.inputrc` with or without the INPUTRC variable exported. I've also tried exporting it from `~/.bashrc` and `~/.profile`, neither has worked.

I could add these lines to my bashrc using `bind` but that would mean that other programs that use readline wouldn't share these options.

Comment: Change `~/` to `"$HOME"` or don't quote the `~/` in the assignment.

Comment: I tried doing both, also tried putting the absolute path to the file, still hasn't worked

Comment: I was hoping you could `$include $HOME/.config/readline/inputrc` in your `.inputrc` but I can't seem to get that to work either /-:

Comment: @tripleee `$HOME` doesn't work in `.inputrc`. With an absolute path it works fine here.

Comment: It's a good idea but I'm trying to adhere to the XDG directory specs and keep my $HOME clean so this would be a last resort

Comment: I tried in a Docker image with an absolute path and it didn't work, but I was probably overlooking something. Thanks for following up.